# How to evaluate$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{-\lambda}}{1+(x+k)^2}dx\text{ , where $\lambda\in(0,1)$ , $k\in(0,+\infty)$}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

How to evaluate$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{-\lambda}}{1+(x+k)^2}dx\text{ , where $\lambda\in(0,1)$ , $k\in(0,+\infty)$}$$

Comment: result= $\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \left(k^2+1\right)^{-\lambda } \left((k-i)^{\lambda }-(k+i)^{\lambda }\right) \csc (\pi  \lambda )$

Comment: @wuyudi Thanks, but I wonder the solution.

Comment: Could you add some context as to where this problem comes from, what you've attempted, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you tagged this question under Real Analysis, but will offer you a solution using Complex Analysis, I hope you don’t mind.

First, let’s  define a keyhole contour with a branch cut in the positive real axis counterclockwise oriented as our integration path and $f(z)=\frac{z^{-\lambda}}{(z+k)^2+1}$. Then:
$$\oint f(z)dz=\left(\int_{ir}^{ir+R}+\int_{\Gamma_R}+\int_{-ir+R}^{-ir}+\int_{\Gamma_r}\right)f(z)dz$$

1)Applying  ML Inequality:
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R}f(z)dz\right|≤2\pi\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{R^{-\lambda+1}}{R^2 +1}\rightarrow0$$
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_r}f(z)dz\right|≤-2\pi\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r^{-\lambda+1}}{r^2 +1}\rightarrow0$$

2) Taking the limits of the RHS of the other two integrals:
$$\lim_{{R\rightarrow\infty}}\lim_{{r\rightarrow0}}\left(\int_{ir}^{ir+R}+\int_{-ir+R}^{-ir}\right)f(z)dz=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-\lambda(log|z|+0i)}-e^{-\lambda(log(|z|+2\pi i)}}{(z+k)^2+1}\right)dz$$
$$\left(1-e^{-2\pi i\lambda}\right)\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{-\lambda}}{(z+k)^2+1}dz$$

3) Computing the residues:
$$\oint f(z)dz=2\pi i\left[Res_{z=-k+i}f(z)+Res_{z=-k-i}f(z)\right]=2\pi i\left[\frac{(-k+i)^{-\lambda}}{2i}-\frac{(-k-i)^{-\lambda}}{2i}\right]$$
Bearing in mind that: $x+yi=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\ arctan(\frac{y}{x})}, x \ and \ y \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\oint f(z)dz=\pi(k^2+1)^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}}\left(e^{i\lambda \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)}-e^{-i\lambda \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)}\right)e^{-i\lambda\pi}$$

Gathering all results:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{-\lambda}}{(z+k)^2+1}dz=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{(1+k^2)^\lambda}}\frac{\color{red}{2i}}{e^{i\lambda\pi}-e^{-\pi i\lambda}}\frac{e^{i\lambda \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)}-e^{-i\lambda \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)}}{\color{red}{2i}}$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{-\lambda}}{(z+k)^2+1}dz=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{(1+k^2)^\lambda}}\frac{sin\left(\lambda arctan\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)}{sin(\pi\lambda)}$$